# How to identify whether a particular file is called first time in C

Tags: c, linux

While executing a C program,A debug print should be inserted to a log file (say log.txt),
but this C program is executed from various places.
So, multiple logs were found in log.txt

I want that debug to be present only once in the log.txt.
How to insert a check in C program to achieve the above requirement
I have tried with static variable, but it works only if for the function called first time
not the file.
whether **access function** would help this scenario??

Comment: Are multiple programs running at the same time all writing to the same log file?

Comment: Do you want multiple programs to only log to the file once? Or do you want only one program to run at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You need some way for the programs to store that they've done a thing, know as a [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)).

Simplest thing to do is use a shared location like `/var/run/` to place a semaphore file. Then each program attempts to create that file. If it already exists, they can assume someone else already performed the action.

To do that we use the [`open`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_(system_call)) system call (not `fopen`) for fine control. Using both the `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL` flags says to create the file, and error if it already exists. This is atomic, we're checking if the file exists and creating it in one action. There's no way two programs could accidentally check & create at the same time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool check_semaphore(const char *file) {
    if( open(file, O_CREAT|O_EXCL) >= 0 ) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

int main() {
    if( check_semaphore("did_debug_log") ) {
        FILE *log = fopen("log.txt", "a");
        if( !log ) {
            perror("Couldn't open log.txt");
        }

        fprintf(log, "Some debug stuff\n");
    }
}
```

You can use more sophisticated shared storage as a semaphore, like shared memory or a shared database such as SQLite, but the basic technique is the same. Check if the operation has been complete while also declaring you're going to do it in an atomic operation.

Comment: The method is ok, but I want to create "did_debug_log" file in particular location.I don't have provision to create in home folder or wherever the c program executed

Comment: @fox18 You can put the file wherever is appropriate for your environment. Perhaps next to the log file.